# jquery create Login Box Dialog secure connection

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am working on sharepoint with jquery and html
I have to create a Login Box Window where I have to input a user name and password
I have found lot of tutorials online:
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/login-box-modal-dialog-window-with-css-and-jquery/#blog

http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/#

My question is: 
I don't need to connect to a database
All I have is one username and one password
so how can I do this in a secure way so  we can only access with the username and password
I appreciate all help

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the required rep to add a comment, so here's an "answer." (bring on the flaming)

Are you building this custom login modal to authenticate a user such that they can access the SharePoint site? It stands to reason that a user has already authenticated if they are able to access a SharePoint page on which your custom components live, but I thought I'd ask anyway. If you *are* authenticating this user to SharePoint then you must be using FBA (forms-based authentication) in which case you are probably leveraging a custom membership provider...which almost certainly hits a data source of some kind.

You mentioned that you are not hitting a database with these credentials; what about another resource, perhaps a web service? If all you are doing is capturing and vetting a predefined set of credentials it sounds to me that the security requirement has more to do with where you store the credentials you use to vet the user's input and how you retrieve them when the user clicks "sign in," correct? If so, here's what I'm thinking (assuming are are deploying a custom solution):

- Store the credentials as application settings in the web.config. Only farm administrators have access to the web.config file. You'd need to run some elevated code on postback to retrieve the application setting values before validating the user's input.
- Store the credentials in a hidden and secured list; run elevated code on postback to retrieve the credentials from the list and make the comparison.

You could also roll your own encryption in either of those two scenarios, if necessary.